# Recursively running a for loop within a for loop (python)

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, recursion

I'm new to python and had the idea of trying to use it to solve the numbers game on the TV show countdown. ([rules for those unfamiliar](http://www.crosswordtools.com/numbers-game/faq.php#rules)). I googled and it turns out [this has been done before](https://github.com/ajvondrak/countdown/) - But I didn't understand the code properly and then thought why not just give it a go myself. I have searched and there are other people looking for recursive solutions but I couldn't get them to work for my example (Apologies, I am very new to this after all).

What I'm trying to do is to take a list of numbers, then loop through applying operations to pairs of them and replacing that pair with the output. This would repeat recursively until either we find the number we are looking for, or the list of numbers is reduced to size 1.

My function "single_move_generator" is a generator producing tuples of the form ((a,b,operation), answer, numbers left to use). I want to feed this final part of the tuple back into the function as the new list, but also keep track of the first part as it is the 'history' of how we achieved our answer. At the moment I have the following:

```
target = 155
numbers_to_use = [6, 25, 3, 2]
for a in single_move_generator(numbers):
    if a[1] == target:
        print(a[0])
    for b in single_move_generator(a[2]):
        if b[1] == target:
                print(a[0],b[0])
                quit()
        for c in single_move_generator(b[2]):
                if c[1] == target:
                    print(a[0],b[0],c[0])
                    quit()
```

produces:

```
(25, 6, 'add') (3, 2, 'add') (31, 5, 'multiply')
```

But I'd like to able to give it a larger list of numbers and have it just continue until the list reaches size one. I suspect I need a while loop - but this attempt doesn't work. It doesn't find the target or keep track of the history of moves.

```
numbers_available = numbers
while len(numbers_available) >1 and target not in numbers_available:

    for a in single_move_generator(numbers_available):
        if a[1] == target:
            print("Target Found", a)           
            break

    numbers_available = a[2]

numbers_available = a[2]
```

I feel like there must be a pythonic way of doing this which is far neater than I've done - any hints would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't find anything recursive in your code. Loop under another loop is known as 'nested loop'.

Comment: What's recursion then? I may have misunderstood. I accept that what I posted was a nested loop, but I wanted to continue that nesting forever (or rather until a certain point was reached but without knowing how many loops that would take)

Comment: Then backtrack is for you. google it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you posted, this should work for you:

```
def solve(numbers, target):
  for op, res, nums in single_move_generator(numbers):
    if res == target:
      return [op]
    ops = solve(nums, target)
    if ops:
      return [op] + ops

print(*solve(numbers_to_use, target))
```

It should be equivalent to the nested for loop you posted.

Bottom of the recursion is hit when `res == target`. Python functions return `None` by default, so if a recursive call to `solve` returned a truthy value then it must have hit the target. `ops` will contain the last operation if it was the bottom of the recursion. It is then appended to the operation that launched the recursive call and returned to an upper level. So the function will return all operations at the top level.

Comment: This is a fix to the problem I encountered - thank you! I didn't realise (or think to check) that functions could call themselves. Thanks for your input

Comment: @Steve To answer your question above. This (a function calling itself) is what is usually understood as recursion and what MASh said he didn't find.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your idea of using tuples `(i, j, operation)`, I wrote the following. This is a recursive solution, as the main function calls itself back.

```
from itertools import combinations, product

def check_operation(i, j, operation):
    """
    Check whether 'i operation j' is permitted.
    """
    if operation == '/' and j == 0:
        return False
    elif operation == '/' and i%j != 0:
        return False
    # if not playing with negative values
    #elif operation == '-' and i-j < 0:
    #    return False
    else:
        return True

def countdown(target, numbers, trackback):
    if target in numbers:
        print trackback
    for possibility in product(combinations(numbers,2), ['+', '*', '/', '-']):
        new_numbers = [k for k in numbers] # copy list, use list.copy in python 3
        i, j = possibility[0][0], possibility[0][1]
        operation = possibility[1]
        new_numbers.remove(i)
        new_numbers.remove(j)
        if not check_operation(i, j, operation):
            continue
        new_numbers.append(eval('%i%s%i' % (i, operation, j)))
        countdown(target, new_numbers, trackback+[possibility])

countdown(155, [6, 25, 3, 2], [])
```

It only works if a solution exists, since it won't intend to get as close to the solution as possible. However it will return all the solutions, not only one.

Comment: Thank you! Itertools looks useful so I'll read up on this more. This is a much cleaner rewrite of my code and provides good food for thought on how I might better have approached it. Appreciate the input :)